# Examples of product risks

Tags: istqb

For this question:

Which of these risks is an example of a product risk:

a. Not enough qualified testers to complete the planned tests

b. Software delivery is behind schedule

c. Threat to a patient's life

d. 3rd party supplier does not supply as stipulated

The answer is c, which I doubt its correctness. Could someone give me an explanation please?

Answer (score 3):

> Product risk is the set of things that could go wrong with the
> service, software or whatever is **being produced** by the project

The other answers are risks off the delivery of the product, not risks of the product itself. The correct answer is C.

Comment: This is the answer! There is a difference between "product" and "process" risk, though a lot of people use these interchangeably.

Answer (score -1):

I understand your doubt, but the correct answer is actually not c, "Threat to a patient's life." This is because "Threat to a patient's life" seems to be more related to a safety or life-critical issue rather than a typical product risk.

Product risks are generally associated with the development, quality, and functionality of a product or system. They can include issues that may affect the product's performance, quality, or delivery. Let's take a look at the other options to clarify:

a. "Not enough qualified testers to complete the planned tests" is an example of a product risk. This risk can impact the thoroughness of testing, which in turn may lead to undetected defects in the product.

b. "Software delivery is behind schedule" is also a product risk. Delays in software delivery can affect project timelines, potentially leading to rushed development and reduced product quality.

d. "3rd party supplier does not supply as stipulated" is a product risk as well. If a third-party supplier fails to deliver components or services as agreed, it can disrupt the product development process and impact product quality.

Product risks are those that affect the development, quality, or delivery of a product, while the threat to a patient's life is more related to safety and ethical considerations, which go beyond typical product risks in industries like software development or manufacturing.

Comment: Um, what if you're developing software for automated driving? That's the product and a threat to a person's life is a risk! Same for software created for airplanes, medical equipment, etc. These all take software to run, it's just that we don't normally think about that if our experience is web, mobile development!